# Filestack error file Cannot find name 'FilestackTransform'.ts(2304) in angular 8

Tags: angular, filestack

[please see this image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmQJF.png)[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7scL0.png) **unable to create build of my angular 8 project throwing Cannot find name FilestackTransform**

```
onUploadSuccess(res: object) {
console.log('###uploadSuccess', res);
this.tempData = res;
this.tempUrl = this.tempData.filesUploaded[0].url;
const client = filestack.init(this.apikey); // initialize Filestack Client with your API key
const tr = new FilestackTransform(); // initialize Transformations UI
tr.setConfigKey('output.blob', true); // set Transformations UI to return blob
tr.open(this.tempUrl).then(res => {
  client.upload(res).then((uploadRes) => { // upload result of the transformation
    this.tempTranssformUrl = JSON.stringify(uploadRes.url, null, 2).split('"');
    (<HTMLImageElement>document.querySelector("#result")).src = this.tempTranssformUrl[1];
    this.isPicker = false;
  })
});
```

}

Comment: how are you using filestack? did you installed its angular library? or cdn or what?

Comment: I have installed filestack SDK and also added transform js library in the header

Answer (score 0):

Inside a class, TypeScript doesn't permit the declaration of class members with
var
let
const

declare FilestackTransform:any;
  const tr = this.FilestackTransform();